# Excel vba is not finding file even though file is present in folder

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the contents of a sheet in a directory to a specific sheet in the current Excel workbook. This is what I have tried so far -

Files I'm trying to copy -

Testfile1.csv
Testfile2.csv

```
Dim reportList As String, reportType As String, partialfilePath As String, filename As String, filePath As String
Dim reportArray() As String
Dim i as Integer

On Error GoTo here

reportList = Range(B1).Value 'B1 value here is = Testfile1,Testfile2
reportArray = Split(reportList, ",")

partialfilePath = Range(B2).Value ''B2 value here is = "E:\test files\excel-sheets"

For i = LBound(reportArray) to UBound(reportArray)
   reportType = "*" & reportArray(i) & "*"
   filename = Dir(partialfilePath & "\" & reportType)
   filePath = (Chr(34) & partialfilePath & "\" & filename & Chr(34))
   Call copySheets(filePath, filename)
Next i

here:

    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Function copySheets(Path As String, filename1 As String)

Workbooks.Open Path

Workbooks(filename1).Worksheets(1).Range("A1:XFD1048576").Copy
Workbooks("Reports").Worksheets(1).Range("A1:XFD1048576")

Workbooks("Reports").Save
Workbooks(filename1).Close

End Function
```

But for some reason, the above code throws the following error -

```
Sorry, we couldn't find "E:\test files\excel-sheet\Testfile1.csv". Is it possible it was moved renamed or deleted?
```

I'm confused that even though it mentions correct path and file name in the error and even though file is available, it still says it's unable to find the file. I even though this might be due to the fact that its a .csv file. But I'm getting the same error .xlsx file as well.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it work when you do not have a space in the path? `test files` contains a space, and usually that is a source of problems.

Comment: Is it `test files` or `test files`? The difference is that the white space can also be `chr(160)`. But it's best you would say where you get the error. I guess it is the line `Workbooks.Open Path`, right?

Comment: You've added quotes around the file path  -those are not needed and are what is causing the problem here.  `filePath = partialfilePath & "\" & filename`

Comment: Also, you need an `Exit Sub` just before  `here:` otherwise you'll always get the msg, even when there was no error

Comment: @JohnB Issue is there even without spaces.
@Storax You are right. Error is in the line ```Workbooks.Open Path```
@chrisneilsen Thanks. Will look into that
@TimWilliams Thank you. This worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
filePath = (Chr(34) & partialfilePath & "\" & filename & Chr(34))
```

You're adding literal quotes to the file path, and that's why you get "file not found"

```
filePath = partialfilePath & "\" & filename
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you. Issue was with Chr(34). Updated to ```filePath = partialfilePath & "\" & filename``` and it worked